# Using SAML Authentication with Bearer Token instead of Cookie

Tags: c#, owin, bearer-token, sustainsys-saml2

I have an application i wrote a few years ago using ASP.NET WEB API 2 with OWIN, ASP.NET Identity, and OAuth with Bearer tokens. My front end is AngularJS. I followed this article when I created the app: https://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Now, I need to implement SAML for authentication purposes only. I will still use ASP.NET Identity for authorization purposes. I am planning on using the Sustainsys SAML2 OWIN middleware. I have followed the OWIN sample here: https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/tree/master/Samples/SampleOwinApplication

The error that I get is:

> A default value for SignInAsAuthenticationType was not found in IAppBuilder Properties. This can happen if your authentication middleware are added in the wrong order, or if one is missing.

How can I add SAML for authentication purposes while still utilizing ASP.NET Identity for authoriziaion via the bearer token solution?

Here is the code I have that does Bearer Authenitcation. I added the UseSam2Authentication method and commented out the UseOAuthBearerAuthenticaton line.

```cs
            var OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthServerProvider(),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60), // TODO: Change this back to 30 minutes!
#if DEBUG
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
#endif
            };

            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
            // app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()); 
            app.UseSaml2Authentication(CreateSaml2Options());
```